# Slurm cluster in Google cloud: Data in mounted directory in controller/login node not available in compute nodes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, slurm, gcsfuse

I have created a slurm cluster following [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/hpc-slurm-on-gcp/#0) tutorial. I have also created a data bucket that stores some data that needs to be accessed in the compute nodes. Since the compute nodes share the home directory of the login node, I mounted the bucket in my login node using [gcsfuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md). However, if I execute a simple script test.py that prints the contents of mounted directory it is just empty. The folder is there as well as the python file.

Is there something that I have to specify in the yaml configuration file that enables having access to the mounted directory?

I have written down the steps that I have taken in order to mount the directory:

When creating the Slurm cluster using

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create google1 --config slurm-cluster.yaml
```

it is important that the node that should mount the storage directory has sufficient permissions.
Ucnomment/add the following in the slurm-cluster.yaml file if your login node should mount the data. (Do the same just with the controller node instead if you prefer).

```
login_node_scopes          :
     - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write
```

Next, log into the log-in node and install gcsfuse. After having installed gcsfuse, you can mount the bucket using the following command

```
gcsfuse --implicit-dirs <BUCKET-NAME> target/folder/
```

Note, the service account which is being attached to your VM has to have access rights on the bucket. You can find the name of the service account in the details of your VM in the cloud console or by running the following command on the VM:

```
gcloud auth list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just got a similar setup working. I don't have a definite answer to why yours isn't, but a few notes:

- gcsfuse is installed per default, no need to explicitly install it.
- You need to wait for the Slurm install to be fully finished before the bucket is available.
- The "devstorage.read_write" appears to be needed.
- I have the following under the login_machine_type in the yaml file:

```
network_storage        :
- server_ip: none
  remote_mount: mybucket
  local_mount: /data
  fs_type: gcsfuse
  mount_options: file_mode=664,dir_mode=775,allow_other
```

Comment: I am not working with this anymore, but the answer might be helpful to others, so thanks!

Comment: @bolind do you mount to both controller and login?

Comment: Yes, if one uses "network_storage" the NFS share is mounted everywhere, login, controller and compute nodes. If you use "login_network_storage" it's only mounted on the login node.